# Can FastMember.ObjectReader take DisplayName into account?

Tags: c#, datagridview, fastmember, displayname-attribute

I'm using FastMember.ObjectReader to copy a list of structs to a DataTable, which I then use as the DataSource of a gridview:

```
struct Foo {
    [DisplayName("title1")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
...
var rows = new List<Foo>();
rows.Add(new Foo { Bar = "somethingsomething" });
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(rows)) {
    table.Load(reader);
}
grid.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
```

If I select the list itself as the DataSource, the DisplayNames are used as column titles instead of the struct member name:

[image]

How can I recreate that when using FastMember.ObjectReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh,  I see what you mean; you want the `IDataReader` to expose the `[DisplayName]` in the metadata; however, the primary way that is exposed is via `GetSchemaTable()`, and AFAIK there is no recognised key to represent `[DisplayName]`. It would be incorrect to pass that as the name, IMO.

Running a quick test:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("foo").Caption = "bar";
var schema = table.CreateDataReader().GetSchemaTable();

foreach(DataRow row in schema.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn col in schema.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{col.ColumnName}={row[col]}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

shows that indeed it is unlikely to expect it there:

```
ColumnName=foo
ColumnOrdinal=0
ColumnSize=-1
NumericPrecision=
NumericScale=
DataType=System.String
ProviderType=
IsLong=False
AllowDBNull=True
IsReadOnly=False
IsRowVersion=False
IsUnique=False
IsKey=False
IsAutoIncrement=False
BaseCatalogName=
BaseSchemaName=
BaseTableName=
BaseColumnName=foo
AutoIncrementSeed=0
AutoIncrementStep=1
DefaultValue=
Expression=
ColumnMapping=1
BaseTableNamespace=
BaseColumnNamespace=
```

this means that there isn't really anything I can suggest other than to manually populate the `.Caption`, perhaps use  fast-member to get the data.

Comment: An answer from the author himself no less!